# How to inject Converter which returns list of generic type in Kotlin?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, generics, converters

My application is implemented on Kotlin and I use spring boot 3.

I have a class like this:

```
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter

@Component
class MyConverter : Converter<SomeResult, List<UserDto>> {
...
}
```

I want to inject it(using interface!!!) to another component:

```
@Service
class MyService(
   private val myConverter : Converter<SomeResult, List<UserDto>>
){
...
}
```

But I receive the error:

> Parameter 1 of constructor in ******.MyService required a bean of type
> 'org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter' that could not
> be found.

How can I fix it ?

### P.S.

This trick perfectly works for converters without generics. For example:

```
Converter<UserDto, AnotherDto>
```

P.S.

My problem is I can't autowire by interface

```
private val myConverter : Converter<SomeResult, List<UserDto>>
```

As a workaround I can autowire by type(and it works)

```
private val myConverter : MyConverter
```

But it doesn't look perfect from my point of view

Comment: if you provide a `@Bean fun myConvertor():Converter<SomeResult, List<UserDto>>  = MyConverter()` via a `@Configuration` class you should be able to inject it to another component

Comment: It depends on how to inject: as class or as interface. As class - yes it works, but I want to inject via interface

Comment: You should be able to inject your converter as an interface, if you provide it as a bean (see answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you provide your converter as a `@Bean`, you should be able to inject this converter (even as an interface)

```java
@Configuration
class MyConfig {
    // return type is interface
    @Bean fun myConverter():Converter<SomeResult, List<UserDto>>  = MyConverter()

}

// @Component <-- does not work 
// provided as Bean in MyConfig <-- works
class MyConverter : Converter<SomeResult, List<UserDto>> {
    override fun convert(source: SomeResult): List<UserDto> {
        return listOf(UserDto())
    }
}

@Service
class MyService(
    private val myConverter : Converter<SomeResult, List<UserDto>>
){
}
```

Comment: Thabk you! It works as magic

Comment: I would appreciate if you could explain why those 2 approaches(@Bean and @Component) lead to different behaviour